# Azure Blob Storage Put Blob from URL from Salesforce

Tags: azure, salesforce, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to put blobs into Azure Blob Storage from Salesforce that are over 12MB. I am using Put Blob from URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob-from-url and i have it working with public images but cannot get it to work with salesforce 'public' links to content documents. I have tried the DistributionPublicUrl and the contentdownloadurl from content distribution but i am getting a Out Of Range error from azure.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Currently using PUT Blob: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob from a remote server to bypass apex limits is not an option.

Comment: What do you mean by `cannot get it to work with salesforce public links`? Is there an error message?

Comment: How large are the blobs you are trying to copy?

Comment: cannot copy any blob from salesforce into blob storage regardless of size using put blob from url. I get this error: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is out of range.